# Minimal diff between two texts

Tags: diff

The iTunes Store Terms and Conditions just changed.

To avoid ending with [random parts of my body being sewn to another person's body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HumancentiPad), I actually read the first version of these Terms and Conditions.

Knowing that I have kept the old terms (as a text file), and that I have the new one, I'm looking for a way to have the shortest list of changes to transform the old terms into the new terms, so that I can check if they changed a verb to *sew* somewhere..

More seriously, `diff -w` gives me the lines that differ, but I would like something more compact.

Comment: You mean less context, or actual highlights of what changed in each differing line? The latter can be gotten by graphical diffs like `xxdiff`, `meld` and probably others

Comment: I will have a look at what xxdiff and meld do before answering.